# Google AdWords API v201802 via Python3 GoogleAds library "ReportDownloadError.INVALID_REPORT_DEFINITION_XML"

Tags: python, google-ads-api

**Problem Description:**

- Using a Google API development key for AdWords. Approved for Standard Access.
- Using the latest version of AdWords API: `v201802`.
- Using the `googleads` Python module to create all my report definitions and subsequent downloads.
- Works on Local, Staging, Demo, and Production environments with the same library code.
- Does not work on the Development server.
- All servers are running Ubuntu 17.10, exception Production which is running 16.10 LTS.
- In the `requirements.txt` file, `googleads>=4.7.0` (this might be the core issue, maybe the version needs to be updated. However, this doesn't explain why the other servers work and Development doesn't.
- Doing a `pip freeze | grep googleads` results in `googleads==10.1.0`, which should be the latest version.

**The error I'm getting:**

```
ReportDownloadError.INVALID_REPORT_DEFINITION_XML
Trigger: Invalid ReportDefinition Xml: cvc-enumeration-valid: 
Value '('CUSTOM_DATE',)' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration 
'[TODAY, YESTERDAY, LAST_7_DAYS, LAST_WEEK, LAST_BUSINESS_WEEK, 
THIS_MONTH, LAST_MONTH, ALL_TIME, CUSTOM_DATE, LAST_14_DAYS, 
LAST_30_DAYS, THIS_WEEK_SUN_TODAY, THIS_WEEK_MON_TODAY, 
LAST_WEEK_SUN_SAT]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

Any ideas or suggestions will help greatly!

**UPDATE:** Updated `pip` using `pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade` and now `pip freeze | grep googleads` results in `googleads==11.0.1` and now my local branch is also not working. So the issue seems to be in the version of `googleads`. Reverting to `10.1.0` as the last known stable version.